# Watch nuxt-auth token changes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Is there anyway to watch token changes via watchState (when new token fetched via refresh token) or any other similar methods? I tried the following way but did not get any success!

```
  this.$auth.$storage.watchState('token', v => {
    console.log('token', v);
  });
```